# GLM in R: How to set the dependent variable as a number of events (rows in dataset)?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmmtmb, dependent-variable

I am carrying out GLMMs with glmmTMB, and my dataset contains rows of video analyses (behaviour analyses of recorded videos of deer) and columns of different data (camera id, date, time, behavioural categories, vegetation, weather, intensity of an experimental treatment, etc.).

I would like to test whether certain behaviours are more or less intense with the experimental treatment, vegetation type, weather, etc. To do this, I simply put the behaviour as dependent variable.

However, I would also like to test the visitation "rates": are cameras near the experimental treatment more or less visited? For this I would like to **simply count the events without actually using a specific variable value** as dependent variable (i.e. the "number of rows").

Is that possible? Or does anyone have a better solution?

Thank you!